# What are the allowed characters in the registration plugin password field?

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration

I am implementing the Facebook Registration plugin on a website and was wondering if anybody was aware of what the allowed characters are for the password field?

I need to know this so I can build a function for updating a password which agrees with the rules for choosing the password in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Facebook's Password Policy is documented publicly. In any case, you should stick to the basics and use an intelligent combination of uppercase, lowercase, digits and commonly used special characters (like @ ! # etc.). Facebook may keep updating their password policy from time to time.